# Spivak, Ch. 3 Functions, Problem 12c: when is $f \circ g$ even/odd, in the four cases when $f$ and $g$ can be either even or odd?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This item of this question asks us to determine whether $f \circ g$ is even or odd, considering the four possible cases when $f$ and $g$ are each either even or odd.

I'm not sure how to write out the condition that $f\circ g$ is even/odd. If I know what the condition is, I can solve all four cases.

If $f \circ g$ is even, does this mean that$f(g(x))=f(-g(x))$ or that $f(g(x))=f(g(-x))$?

Here is one case.

Case 1: $f$ and $g$ both even
$$(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x))=f(g(-x))=f(-g(-x))$$

We could have also written
$$f(g(x))=f(-g(x))$$
directly. This seems like the condition that $f \circ g$ is even, but I didn't have to use the fact that $g$ is even, so I am not sure if this is correct.

Comment: let $h = f\circ g$. Then $h$ being even mean $h(x)=h(-x)$ and $h$ odd means $h(x)=-h(x)$. Can you translate these back into equations with $f$ and $g$? Also, you are correct that you may not have to use every property in every case.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the definitions.

The function $f\circ g$ is even if:
$$
f\circ g (-x) = f\circ g(x),\quad x\in\mathbb{R}\tag{1}
$$
where for simplicity, we assume that the domain of both $f$ and $g$ is $\mathbb{R}$. By the definition of function compositions, (1) is the same as $f(g(-x))=f(g(x))$.

Thus if $g$ is even, (1) holds for whatever $f$.

If $g$ is odd, *and* $f$ is odd, one has
$$
f(g(-x))=f(-g(x))=f(g(x))
$$
and (1) also holds.

You can discuss other cases similarly.

In summary,

- if $g$ is even, then $f\circ g$ even no matter what $f$ is;
- if $g$ odd, then $f\circ g$  has the same parity as that of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is to fill the following array, ie check the four cases :

$\begin{array}{c|c|c} \ {} & f \textrm{ even} & f \textrm{ odd} \\
\hline g \textrm{ even} & f \circ g \ ? & f \circ g \ ? \\
\hline g \textrm{ odd} & f \circ g \ ? & f \circ g \ ? \end{array}$

For example, assume $f$ and $g$ are both even. Take an arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have :
$$f\circ g(-x) = f(g(-x)) = f(g(x)) = f \circ g (x)$$
Hence, in this case $f \circ g$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: $f$ and $g$ both even
$$(f \circ g)(-x) = f(g(-x))=f(g(x))=(f \circ g)(x),$$ so $(f \circ g)$ is even.

Case 2: $f$ and $g$ both odd
$$(f \circ g)(-x) = f(g(-x))=f(-g(x))=-f(g(x))=-(f \circ g)(x),$$ so $(f \circ g)$ is odd.

Etc.

Comment: There is a typo in the first equation I believe, last part of it. Edits by me have to be at least six characters so I can't fix it.

Comment: @evianpring Got it; rectified; thanks!